# Image slider dinámico en Laravel, esconder las demás imágenes

Tags: javascript, laravel, slider, blade, carrusel

¿Cómo puedo hacer un image slider dinámico en Laravel? He podido mostrar la primera imagen y manetener las que le siguen "ocultas" pero no puedo hacer que al hacer clic en el botón la primera se "esconda" y que las que le siguen, que se vean:

```
<x-faro-posts-img-modal hash="faro-posts-img-modal-{{$post->id}}">

    <div class="slider-items">
        @foreach($post->images as $image)
        <div class="inset-0 flex items-center justify-between md:w-96 h-full mx-auto
                                            {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : 'hidden'}}">
            <img src="{{ $image->name }}" alt="gallery" class="h-full">
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="w-full absolute flex items-center justify-between">
        <x-left-chevron />

        <x-right-chevron />
    </div>
</x-faro-posts-img-modal>
```

Esto me permite ver la primer imagen pero no las demás cuando hago clic sobre el botón; para ver la primera usé la variable de `$loop` de Blade, pero ¿cómo puedo hacer que se vean las demás al presionar ese botón?

Este es mi Javascript:

```
var slides = document.querySelector('.slider-items').children;
var nextSlide = document.querySelector('.right-slide');
var prevSlide = document.querySelector('.left-slide');
var totalSlides = slides.length;
var index = 0;

nextSlide.onclick = function () {
     next("next");
}

prevSlide.onclick = function () {
     next("prev");
}

function next(direction) {

   if (direction == "next") {
        index++;
        if (index == totalSlides) {
            index = 0;
        }
   }

   else {
        if (index == 0) {
            index = totalSlides-1;
        }
        else {
            index--;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length;i++) {
        slides[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

  slides[index].classList.add("active");     
}
```

La verdad es que no entiendo qué sucede con los demás divs cuando tengo ese `$loop`, ya que he tratado varias formas:

```
{{ $loop->index || $loop->iteration ? 'active' : 'hidden' }}
```

O sea que tome en cuenta la primera iteración (la posición 0) y las que le siguen después de esa (posición 1) sean incluidas en el if. Esto lo tendría que llevar a cabo el botón porque es el que quita o pone la clase de `active`, pero esto ni siquiera muestra la primera imagen.

Otro camino ha sido:

Poner en el div hijo de `.slider-items` la clase `.active`, y en la imagen lo siguiente:

```
{{ $loop->remaining ? 'active' : 'hidden'}}
```

O sea que el primer hijo de `slider-items` tendrá la clase de `.active` y también consigo ver la primer foto del array, pero las imagenes después de esa no se pueden ver. He tratado estos y muchos otros caminos pero ninguno me ha dado resultado.

Comment: El problema es que solo asignas la clase `active`, pero no eliminas la otra. Creo que no deberías usar la clase `hidden` y, por defecto, las imágenes no activas estarán ocultas.

Comment: Pero a que te refieres que por defecto no estarán ocultas? El problema está en que se siguen viendo sin esa clase. Por ejemplo en CSS necesitas 2 clases, una clase que tenga un ```display:none``` y otra con un ```display:block``` y así se puede tener un control sobre cuales se verán y cuales no. Necesito asignarle a un elemento un display none si no nunca se van a ocultar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tus estilos CSS, por defecto, vas a ocultar todos los elementos del slider; Con la propiedad `display` puedes lograrlo, pero no es la mejor opción si deseas aplicar animaciones, se usa `> div` en el selector para seleccionar solo los hijos directos:

```
/* Ocultar todos los elementos */
.slider-items > div {
    display:none;
}
/* Mostrar solo el que tenga la clase active */
.slider-items > div.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Al generar los elementos en el ciclo, asegúrate de asignar la clase `active` solo al primer elemento:

```
<div class="slider-items">
    @foreach($post->images as $image)
    <div class="inset-0 flex items-center justify-between md:w-96 h-full mx-auto
        {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <img src="{{ $image->name }}" alt="gallery" class="h-full">
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

La parte importante es `{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}` donde solo se asigna la clase al primer elemento y el resto queda con cadena vacía.

Con estos pequeños cambios tu slider va a funcionar correctamente.

Comment: No tenía un CSS para esto, osea que voy a necesitar un CSS. No me lo esperaba.

Comment: Que bien pues esto _si_ funciona pero resulta que tengo 2 posts y ambas tienen varias imágenes. Sólo en el primer set de fotos puedo avanzar o retroceder, el segundo no funciona.

Comment: Eso es porque tu script está creado para tomar en cuenta solo un slider, no más.

Comment: No sabía, existe alguna manera de hacerlo que funcione para un número ilimitado de sliders??

Comment: Sí la hay, pero implica reescribir todo el script y, tal vez, meter todo en una función o clase.

Comment: Pudiera conseguir otro pero el problema va a estar en cómo funcione ese. No sé como se adecue el blade a ese nuevo script.

Comment: Lo ideal sería crear una nueva pregunta. Más tarde la busco y, si tengo oportunidad, trataré de ayudarte a resolverlo.